# Angular 9 ¿Cómo refrescar el index de un crud, una vez eliminado un elemento?

Tags: javascript, angular, api

Muy buenas, tengo un crud de administradores en angular 9, el cual realiza peticiones a un API, al eliminar un admin, se despliega un modal de confirmación, al aceptar, el admin se elimina satisfactoriamente, pero tengo que refrescar la pantalla para que se puedan observar los cambios, la información viaja de la siguiente manera:

index -> admin-card -> delete-modal

en el index.ts tengo lo siguiente:

```
  constructor(private adminService: AdminService) {
    this.adminService.readAdmin()
    .subscribe(
        response =>{
            this.adminsLoading=false; 
            this.adminList=response;
        });
  }
```

Ese 'adminList' es un arreglo que se le pasa al componente hijo (admin-card) en la vista del index, ejemplo (index.html):

```
<div *ngFor="let admins of adminList" fxFlex="32" fxFlex.lt-md="100" fxFlex.lt-sm="100">
    <app-admin-card [admin]="admins" class="mat-elevation-z2"></app-admin-card>
</div>
```

Luego, en el componente admin-card, se le envía el 'admin.id' (desde el admin-card.html) al modal para eliminar el admin. Este es el método que tengo en admin-card.ts:

```
 openDeleteDialog() {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteModalComponent,{
        data: {
          adminData: this.admin
        }
      });
```

posteriormente, la info es enviada al modal el cual tiene dos botones (cancelar y confirmar), al hacer click en confirmar se ejecuta deleteAdmin(), anexo el código de la función:

```
  deleteAdmin(){
    let id = this.data.adminData.id;
    let password = this.firstFormGroup.value.pass;
    this.adminService.deleteAdmin(id, password)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.closeDialog();
        this.snackBar.open(
          'Administrador eliminado satisfactoriamente', 'Cerrar', {
            duration: 3000
          })
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.closeDialog();
        this.snackBar.open(
          'Se ha producido un error', 'Cerrar', {
            duration: 3000
          })
      }
      );
  }
```

y por último, anexo el codigo de la función que realiza la petición al API para eliminar el admin (admin.service.ts):

```
deleteAdmin(id: number, password){
    return this.http.delete(environment.url+'/admins/'+id, password);
}
```

Comment: Dices que no se te actualiza esa información si no hasta que recargues la pagina, y eliminas satisfactoriamente información del admin en la BD, sospecho que se te ha olvidado eliminar en tu lista de admins en el frontend el admin que se elimino de manera correcta, creo que es una solución bastante sencilla.

Comment: correcto, la cuestión está en eliminarlo del front, si no existiera el modal y lo elminara desde el index pulsando un botón sería super sencillo, pero no es caso, lo que no entiendo es como eliminar ese elemento desde el modal (que es otro componente independiente del index), o si tengo que modificar algo en el servicio. Disculpen soy un novato en angular

Comment: Ummmm según entiendo ya haz logrado enviar la información al modal de manera correcta, creo que se puede hacer alrevez también para luego actualizar tu información en la otra parte.

Comment: Una vez lei en stackoverflow hace mas o menos 1 mes una respuesta sobre event emitters que te ayudan a transportar información de un componente a otro cuando lo requieras, pero pues no manejo el event emiter y no he vuelto a ver la publicación... pero creo que puede ser útil en este caso, tendrías que consultar sobre event emitter de angular para transportar por ejemplo el id de la informacion eliminada desde el modal al componente que abrio el modal, y una vez tengas la data, hacer la respectiva actualización de datos (eliminarlo en tu arreglo de admins).

Comment: no entiendo muy bien tu caso. Pero cuando cierras el dialog no puedes redireccionar al index? O volver a hacer el get del listado de admins? Con eso ya se actualizaria la vista

Comment: @hawks es que supongo que el manda ciertos datos al modal, datos que no están directamente ligados a la ventana que abrió el modal (copia sin referencia), es por eso que aunque los datos se borren en el modal, luego tendría que borrarlos en el listado de admins que tiene tambien el cual se encuentra en la ventana que abrio el modal, segun veo el para transportar informacion al modal lo hace por medio de una funcion especial que tiene el modal, pero para hacerlo a la inversa no existe... asi que supongo que esa es la duda que tiene el OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el diseño de tu aplicación para mi lo mas conveniente seria que declararas un `EventEmitter` en tu servicio y te suscribieras desde el componente que quieres refrescar.

Solo bastaría esta línea en tu servicio

```
 cambio = new EventEmitter<boolean>()
```

Y desde donde quieras detectar el cambio inyectas tu servicio, como hasta ahora y te suscribes a la propiedad de esta manera:

```
 this.usuarioService.cambio.subscribe(cambioOError=>{

      if(cambioOError){ 
        //... Tu logica
      }
    })
```

Yo uso "cambioOerror" solo por ejemplo, pero en realidad puedes dejarlo que en cuanto se detecte algo se ejecute tu lógica, sin el `if`, esto ya depende de ti. También es posible pasar otros datos.

Te dejo un ejemplo [funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aknq7m)

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el change detector pueda ayudarte, en ciertos casos cuando esto no pasa tienes que usar el método detectChanges de la clase ChangeDetectorRef, (mas info acá https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Solo necesitas inyectar el `ChangeDetectorRef` y después invocar el método `detectChanges();` cuando hayas terminado de traer y asignar tus datos en la subscripción de tu observable.

```js
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

deleteAdmin(){
    let id = this.data.adminData.id;
    let password = this.firstFormGroup.value.pass;
    this.adminService.deleteAdmin(id, password)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.closeDialog();
        this.snackBar.open(
          'Administrador eliminado satisfactoriamente', 'Cerrar', {
            duration: 3000
          })

        // Aquí se forza el redibujado de la app
        this.cd.detectChanges();


      },
      error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.closeDialog();
        this.snackBar.open(
          'Se ha producido un error', 'Cerrar', {
            duration: 3000
          })
      }
      );
  }
```

Igual acá hay una explicación genial de la estrategoia de detección de cambios que usa Angular https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

Igual no estaría de mas que des una revisada a la arquitectura de tu aplicación pues usar detectChanges(), a pesar de se una herramienta muy útil no es muy recomendada pues estas "cargando" de más tu app y el performance de tu app ppuede verse afectado considerablemente.